# Material 2 how to open a Bottom Sheet in a child view

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5

How do you make the Bottom Sheet component appear inside a view like a card not just at the bottom of the screen? Using version 6.0.1.

From the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/api) specifying viewContainerRef in options should have some effect, but in the example nothing happens.

demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfpaa2?file=app/bottom-sheet-overview-example.ts

Comment: check out the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824759/angular-open-bottom-sheet-matbottomsheet-inside-parent-container/61006796#61006796