# Angular - Open Bottom Sheet (MatBottomSheet) inside parent container

Tags: angular, angular-material, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to open a material bottom sheet inside a div container, as default it's opening as the last element inside the body.

Looking at the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/api), I need to use the `viewContainerRef`, but I can't make it work.

This is similiar to what I'm trying to do:

app.component.html:

```
...
<div #container></div>
...
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container;

    ...

    constructor(
        private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    ) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.bottomSheet.open(MySheetComponent, {
            panelClass: 'my-modal',
            viewContainerRef: this._container,
        });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to make any change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm seemingly having the same issue. It seems the ViewContainerRef doesn't do anything. I'm using the latest Angular version (8.x.x)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a misunderstanding of what `viewContainerRef` option really means.

The `MatBottomsheet` is created with `ComponentPortal`. From `ComponentPortal` [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#ComponentPortal), we can found a more detailed description of `viewContainerRef`:

> Where the attached component should live in Angular's **logical** component tree.
>
> #### This is different from where the component renders,
>
> which is determined by the PortalOutlet. The origin is necessary when the host is outside of the Angular application context.

When inspecting the DOM when a bottomsheet is opened, we'll find the following component hierarchy:

1. **`OverlayContainer`** - `<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>`
2. **`Overlay`** - `<div id="cdk-overlay-{id}" class="cdk-overlay-pane">`
3. **`ComponentPortal`** - `<bottom-sheet-container></bottom-sheet-container>`
4. **`Component`** - our `BottomSheet`.

Now, what we really need to change is the `OverlayContainer`, which, according to [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#the-overlay-container), is:

> the container element in which all individual overlay elements are
>   rendered.
>
> #### By default, the overlay container is appended directly to the document body.

Technically it is possible to provide a **custom** overlay container:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer}],
 // ...
})
export class MyModule { }

export class AppOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {

  protected _createContainer(): void {
    const container: HTMLDivElement = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('app-overlay-container');

    const element: Element | null = document.querySelector('#custom-overlay-contaier');
    if (element !== null) {
      element.appendChild(container);
      this._containerElement = container;
    }
  }
}
```

but, unfortunately, it is a **singleton** and creates a new problem:

`MatBottomSheet`, `MatDialog`, `MatSnackbar`, `MatTooltip` components use the same OverlayContainer, so all these components will open within this custom container.